# CVS: Create a new offline branch for private project

Tags: merge, branch, cvs

I downloaded some CVS code using the checkout command from sourceforge. Now, I want to create my own branch because my changes are completely unrelated to the official project and I wanted to work on it offline myself.

When I start to by entering this command:

```
cvs tag branchname_0
```

I receive an error:

```
error: cvs [server aborted]: "tag" requires write access to the repository
```

A colleague recommended that, instead of CVS, I should simply use Git to create that branch. Basically, I want to be able to make changes but not lose the capability of merging my own changes with that from the project's developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CVS branch is not necessary.  You can checkout
and merge new commits from other developers using a `cvs update` command
without a new branch.

The main problem is that you have no write access to the Sourceforge
CVS repository and will never be able to commit your own changes
to that repository.

I have worked on Sourceforge projects where I did not have write permissions
to the CVS repository.  I e-mailed my changes to a project
administrator with write permission and that person reviewed and checked in my changes.
After e-mailing several change sets, the project
administrators accept that my work is acceptable and
give me write permission to the CVS repository.  I believe this
series of events occurs quite often.

Comment: Many thanks for your input Simon. After doing some research, I have now chosen to use Git offline for further development. Basically, I check out the source with CVS, initialize it with Git and then create my branches from there. As soon as something changes, I update the master branch (inserting new CVS stuff) and use the rebase command to put everything back together. I've chosen this approach because my changes are not really helping anyone as they are very specific to my project.